# Laravel not storing specific form data in database without giving an error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am storing form input in laravel, and almost everything works fine the other form inputs are correctly stored but not my color codes.

The names are correct otherwise i would get an error while updating and storing. Here is what i have.

laravel db table columns

```
 $table->string('color_code_1')->default('#006661');
 $table->string('color_code_2')->default('#006661');
 $table->string('color_code_3')->default('#006661');
```

form values send to api

```
 color_code_1: #006661
 color_code_2: #006664
 color_code_3: #006661
```

Controller storing values

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $user->cases()->whereId($id)->first()->update($input);

    return redirect('/admin/cases');
}
```

This is working fine for all my other values but these three values just wont change in the db.

Maybe it has something to do with their hex values but i couldnt figure it out.

Does someone have an idea? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: add this column to fillable array

Comment: Are the `color_code_*` columns added to the `$fillable` array in the model?

Comment: Where does `$user` come from?

Comment: Well i guess that fixed it lol, thanks a lot both of you!

Comment: Fine. Glad we could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution edit the fillable in my model

```
   protected $fillable = [
        'color_code_1',
        'color_code_2',
        'color_code_3',
      ];
```